# Why does NTP need to implement leap seconds?

Tags: date, datetime, time, synchronization, timestamp

I've recently learned that NTP implements handling of leap seconds. I was really surprised, as I know that NTP stores time as just amount of seconds since January 1, 1900. Shouldn't the issue of leap seconds only be addressed during formatting of the date to human-readable form, as it is the case with leap years?

Comment: Leap seconds are not counted, just repeated if they occur. However, NTP knows a special leap second flag which does not indicate the actual timestamp as leap second but shall instruct sysadmins to be aware of coming leap second event.

Comment: By "Leap seconds are not counted, just repeated if they occur" do you mean that the same unix timestamp is repeated?

Comment: Yes, see also the NTP-protocol paper or this [source](http://doc.ntp.org/4.1.2/leap.htm) which states: "NTP timescale has no knowledge of or provision for any of these eclectic seconds" so during a leap second when any effort of synchronization with computer clock must be performed the lexical representation of leap second is usually repeated while the unix timestamp counting seconds since an epoch (in NTP: since 1900) remains the same.

Comment: The source mentions that NTP time stops during the leap second - and that's what's bugging me. should the NTP time grow independently of leap seconds? It makes as little sense to me as would stopping the NTP time for entire day each February 29th

Comment: "stops" means "repeating the same timestamp representation". And this is not just theory but has been observed by myself in my own practical tests setting up a [SNTP-client defined in my lib Time4J](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/clock/SntpConnector.html) connecting to ptb.de (NTP-stratum-1 in Germany). Unfortunately, the leap second indicator of NTP-protocol is NOT a suitable mean to identify repeated timestamps as leap seconds.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I'm still baffled - why is the timestamp repeated? Wouldn't it be easier and more elegant if it just was strictly monotonic?

Comment: POSIX, Microsoft, SQL, and just about every other specification for time in computers all say that leap seconds do not, must not, exist. Therefore when a leap second happens all those schemes must not count that second, and must not allow applications to know that a second labelled 23:59:60 UTC is in progress or ever happened at all.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Strange how inconsistent that thing is - I wonder why do these specifications don't say that Feb 29th must not exist, as well...

Comment: Because whereas the 1988 POSIX committee believed that people would notice the computer being off by a day, they did not believe that computers kept time accurate to a second. Different groups believe different things about how time should work http://www.ucolick.org/~sla/leapsecs/picktwo.html
and their lack of agreement leads to confusion.